# How to print and display the given input binary tree in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

how to print the given binary tree in java? Following is my code:

JAVA code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class binaryexpample1 {

public static void main(String[] args){

         BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x1 = input.nextInt();
        BNode root = bt.addRoot(x1);
        int x2 = input.nextInt();
        BNode y1 = bt.insertLeft(root,x2);
        int x3 = input.nextInt();
        BNode y2 = bt.insertRight(root,x3);
        int x4= input.nextInt();
        BNode y3 = bt.insertLeft(y1,x4);
        int x5 = input.nextInt();
        BNode y4 = bt.insertRight(y1,x3);
        int x6 = input.nextInt();
        BNode y5=bt.insertLeft(y2,x6);
        int x7= input.nextInt();
        BNode y6 = bt.insertRight(y2,x7);
        int x8 = input.nextInt();
        system.out,println()
    }
}
```

Please suggest a method to implement this.

Comment: well the first thing you can do is get that comma out of here and put a period in your system.out.println().  Second, try actually putting something in between the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use an in-order traversal method,

```
public void inOrder(BNode root) {
    if(root == null) {
        return;
    }
    inOrder(root.left);
    System.out.println(root.value);
    inOrder(root.right);
}
```

And in your main call it like so,

```
inOrder(bt.root);
```

How in-order traversal works is that it will go down the left side of a node by calling `inOrder`. Once those recursive calls have finished, the value/data of the current node will be printed. Then the right side of the node will be traversed by calling `inOrder` many times.